# how to define an extensible C++ enum system

Tags: c++, templates, macros, enums

I have encounter a problem in my project on enums. 
In EventDef.h,

```
enum EventDef {
    EVT1 = 0,
    EVT2,
    EVT3,
    EVT_NUM,
}
```

In this way, I can extend the EventDef system in another header UIEventDef.h by

```
#include "EventDef.h"
enum UIEventDef {
    UIEVT1 = EVT_NUM,
    UIEVT2,
    UIEVT3,
}
```

But, there is a limitation that i can not do this in NetEvent.h the same way.

```
#include "EventDef.h"
enum NetEventDef {
    NETEVT1 = EVT_NUM,
    NETEVT2,   //wrong: this will have the same value as UIEVT2
    NETEVT3,  
}
```

Is there a better compile time solution in C++ such as templates that can help ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem of having the same value? The types differ(UIEventDef vs. NetEventDef) anyway, so you should probably not be comparing them.

Comment: btw, I have used the __COUNTER__ macro, but sadly it dont work :(

Comment: to zxcdw. I have a switch-case event handler, so i need they have different values. yes, i can give them categories, but i just want a better and flexible solution

Comment: @rechardchen: What is it that you want to achieve? The purpose of enums is providing *different* types so that even if the same values that will not matter. You are basically trying to achieve the opposite: a single range that has different values in different headers... You should state the problem that you want to *solve* rather than asking how to deal with your *broken* design.

Comment: @rechardchen: Providing categories is a *better more flexible solution* than a single enum in all respects.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: i think the purpose of enum is not only providing type-checking. The problem is to define different id for different events, but the system need to be flexible( in different headers ).whether to use enum is not the issue

Answer (score 7):

The idea of extensible enums is not inherently "bad design". In other languages there is a history of them, even if c++ does not support them directly. There are different kinds of extensibility.

Things that extensible enums would be useful for

- error codes
- message types
- device identification (OIDs are a hierarchical enum like system)

Examples of enum extensibility

- Objective Modula Two has enums that are extensible with a class like inheritance.
- [The Extensible Enum Pattern in Java](http://binkley.blogspot.com/2005/11/extensible-enum-pattern-in-java.html), which can be implemented in c++.
- Java enums are extensible in that extra data and methods can be a part of an enum.
- In c++, the typeid operator is essentially a compiler generated enum with attached values.

The kind of extensibility you showed in your sample code does not have an elegant implementation in unaided c++. In fact, as you pointed out, it easily leads to problems.

Think about how you are wanting to use an extensible enum.  Perhaps a set/map of immutable singleton objects will meet your needs.

Another way to have extensible enums in c++ is to use a code generator.  Every compilation unit that wants to add to an extensible enum, records the ids in its own, separate, .enum file.  At build time, before compilation, a script (ie perl, bash, ...) looks for all .enum files, reads them, assigns numeric values to each id, and writes out a header file, which is included like any other.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want your event enums to be declared like that? What do you gain by having them 'linked' if you will, they way you describe?

I would make them completely independent enums. Secondly, I recommend you not use the old style enums anymore. c++11 is here and available in gcc. You should use enum classes:

```
enum class EventDef  : unsigned { Evt1 = 0, Evt2, Evt3, ... LastEvt }
enum class NetEvtDef : unsigned { NetEvt1 = 0, NetEvt2, NetEvt3, ... NetLastEvt }
```

If you are switching you can do this:

```
void doSwitch(EventDef evt_def)
{
  switch(evt_def)
  {
    case EventDef::Evt1
    {
     // Do something;
     break;
    }
    default:
    // Do something;
  };
}

void doSwitch(NetEvtDef net_def)
{
  switch(net_def)
  {
    case NetEvtDef::NetEvt1
    {
     // Do something;
     break;
    }
    default:
    // Do something;
  };
}
```

By creating an overloaded function for doSwitch you segregate all your enum types. Having them in separate categories is a benefit not a problem. It provides you the flexibility to deal with each event enum type differently.

Chaining them together as you describe needlessly complicates the problem.

I hope that helps.

Comment: good, thank you to let me know the new c++11 style enum. :) Does it work in VS2008 and xcode4.x? I think what i want to archive is something like categories in objective-C ..

Comment: There are situations when you need extensible enum classes. And overloading switching function seems like a crutch to me.

Answer (score 0):

I find the following a useful compromise between complexity, features, and type safety. It uses global variables of a custom class that has a default constructor to make initialisation easy. The example below is an extendable set of error codes. You might want to enclose within a name space also (but I typically don't bother).

```
//
//  ErrorCodes.h
//  ExtendableEnum
//
//  Created by Howard Lovatt on 10/01/2014.
//

#ifndef ErrorCodes_h
#define ErrorCodes_h

#include <string>

class ErrorCodes {
public:
    static int nextValue_;
    explicit ErrorCodes(std::string const name) : value_{nextValue_++}, name_{name} {}
    ErrorCodes() : ErrorCodes(std::to_string(nextValue_)) {}
    int value() const { return value_; }
    std::string name() const { return name_; }
private:
    int const value_;
    std::string const name_;
    ErrorCodes(const ErrorCodes &);
    void operator=(const ErrorCodes &);
};

int ErrorCodes::nextValue_ = 0; // Weird syntax, does not declare a variable but rather initialises an existing one!
ErrorCodes first;
ErrorCodes second;
// ...

#endif


//
//  ExtraErrorCodes.h
//  ExtendableEnum
//
//  Created by Howard Lovatt on 10/01/2014.
//

#ifndef ExtraErrorCodes_h
#define ExtraErrorCodes_h

#include "ErrorCodes.h"

ErrorCodes extra{"Extra"};

#endif


//
//  ExtraExtraExtraCodes.h
//  ExtendableEnum
//
//  Created by Howard Lovatt on 10/01/2014.
//

#ifndef ExtendableEnum_ExtraExtraCodes_h
#define ExtendableEnum_ExtraExtraCodes_h

#include "ErrorCodes.h"

ErrorCodes extraExtra{"ExtraExtra"};

#endif


//
//  main.cpp
//  ExtendableEnum
//
//  Created by Howard Lovatt on 10/01/2014.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorCodes.h"
#include "ExtraErrorCodes.h"
#include "ExtraExtraErrorCodes.h"

// Need even more error codes
ErrorCodes const localExtra;

int main(int const notUsed, const char *const notUsed2[]) {
    std::cout << first.name() << " = " << first.value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << second.name() << " = " << second.value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << extra.name() << " = " << extra.value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << extraExtra.name() << " = " << extraExtra.value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << localExtra.name() << " = " << localExtra.value() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0 = 0
1 = 1
Extra = 2
ExtraExtra = 3
4 = 4
```

If you have multiple compilation units then you need to use a variation on the singleton pattern:

```
class ECs {
public:
    static ErrorCode & first() {
        static ErrorCode instance;
        return instance;
    }
    static ErrorCode & second() {
        static ErrorCode instance;
        return instance;
    }
private:
    ECs(ECs const&);
    void operator=(ECs const&);
};
```

Comment: Added that if you have multiple compilation units then, as always you have to use static access methods to overcome initialisation order and multiple definitions.

Answer (score 0):

We can construct an extensible “enum” in C++ as follows:

```
struct Last {};

struct D 
{
    using Next = Last;
    static const char* name = “D”;
};

struct C
{
    using Next = D;
    static const char* name = “C”;
};

struct B 
{
    using Next = C;
    static const char* name = “B”;
};

using First = B;
```

We can iterate thru the above using these constructs:

```
void Process(const B&)
{
    // do something specific for B
    cout << “Call me Ishmael” << endl;
}

template <class T>
void Process(const T&)
{
    // do something generic
    cout << “Call me “ << T::name << endl;
}

template <class T>
struct IterateThru
{
   static void iterate() 
   {
       Process(T());
       IterateThru<T::Next>::iterate();
   }
};

template <>
struct IterateThru<Last>
{
    static void iterate()
   {
       // end iteration
   }
};
```

To iterate through the “enumeration”:

```
IterateThru<First>::iterate();
```

To extend the “enumeration”:

```
struct A
{
    using Next = B;
    static const char* name = “A”;
}:

using First = A:
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog post on how to do this, except with enum classes: [C++ Extending Enums](https://radiantsoftware.hashnode.dev/c-extending-enums)

What you end up with is something like this, where the FirstEnum, LastEnum values are used to guard against enum overlaps (doesn't fully prevent intentional abuses though):

```
enum class EventDef {
    EVT1 = 0,
    EVT2,
    EVT3,
    FirstEnum = EVT1,
    LastEnum = EVT3
};

enum class UIEventDef {
    UIEVT1 = EventDef::LastEnum + 1,
    UIEVT2,
    UIEVT3,
    FirstEnum = UIEVT1,
    LastEnum = UIEVT3
};

template <>
struct EnumExtension<EventDef> { using ExtensionType = UIEventDef; };
```