# N symbols with different value in compile time

Tags: c++, templates, enums

The raw problem is [SO 12118654](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118654/how-to-define-an-extensible-c-enum-system/12118799#12118799)

But what I really want to do is define N const symbols with different values in compile time.
The N symbols will be separated in several headers.

I hope for an elegant C++ solution, maybe using templates etc

Comment: I think we could help you better if you described what problem your trying to solve. Currently I don't understand what your trying to do.

Comment: @anio, if this is the problem?